# Micro-services - decision on technology/platform

Tags: microservices

Is it good architecture of an application if,
I am using multiple technologies leveraging strong points of each.
for example:
Encryption in python,
integration of services in java etc.
or should I stick to one technology like Java as I am comfortable with it?
Also the reason for this question is I am thinking of developing a new application in which speed is a major concern, I am targeting to attain.

Also Database that I am preferring for now is MongoDb.

Any suggestions on the Technologies apart from these technologies?

Also will this approach help in speeding up the application?

Comment: What is the best practice for a situation where I have all of my services written in Java whereas one is in Python and one of these many java services communicates with the Python and gets its output for further processing, now the implementation that I have done in Python can be done in Java as well should I translate the Python service to java if yes will it in anyway degrade or enhance the speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the main application in one language only is a easier approach than dividing your application and attempting to write pieces in each language that is best suited for the task, unless you are fluent in a few languages and the ones chosen are particularly suited to specific groups of tasks that make up parts of the functionality.

Because MongoDB has a [Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) there's nothing wrong with writing your main application in Java and relying on libraries written in other languages (MongoDB is [written](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) in C++, C and JavaScript).

As long as other works you need to rely on are well maintained there's no reason to switch from your preferred language to match what any of your libraries are using.

If you add artificial intelligence to your program in the future and part of the code is to run on a GPU you are forced to have a program that is a hybrid; learning a new language along with the details of the underlying algorithms is certainly more of a burden than learning the API.

Decide where to draw the line, what you will write in your preferred language and what will be written by others. It's certainly better to choose libraries and programs that you interface with written in languages you understand (assuming that they are open source). If what you interface with has no source available it becomes a 'black box' which simply must work, there are occasions when that is acceptable and occasional when there is no choice.